# function returned without value 06503

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have this function with only returns incorrect data but I am getting this error message

"function returned without value" when I run my query.

***function***

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION date_chk(p_value VARCHAR2, p_format VARCHAR2)
RETURN NUMBER
AS
  v_val1 NUMBER(10);
  v_date DATE;
BEGIN
  v_date := TO_DATE(p_value,p_format);
  RETURN 1;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    IF SQLCODE = -01858 THEN
      RETURN 0;
    END IF;
END;
```

**Query**

```
SELECT sid,
       sid,
       sentry,
       daytime
FROM test_table
```

WHERE date_chk(daytime,'HH24:MI') = 0;

**Edited**

For example if daytime had something like `09:99` it will come up with this error message but if it was `abshaasj` it will return those value. I am trying to return both numbers and letters if any of them is found in any of my records. I have 10345 records and a lot of them as the return time format.

Comment: I don't know if this is what's happening when you run it, but if there is an exception and SQLCODE != -01858 it won't return a value.

Comment: Your exception handler must return a value even if `if` condition doesnot hold.

Comment: @charlieparker the example error which should return for the daytime in my test database is `09:99` of-course `09:99` is not a real time but if I change it to any letter it will return those letters.

Comment: Put an `ELSE` block in your exception. The error raised doesn't have a code -01858 so the `if` condition won't catch it. You need to handle the other possible exceptions also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check correctness of a datetime information provided as a character literal, it seems that way, you can get, besides `ORA-01858`, plenty of other exceptions, depending on incorrectness of datetime value or/and format. You can, of course, write as many `IF` conditions, or better yet, associate an exception name with an exception number by using `exception_init()` pragma, as many exceptions can be potentially raised, or you can declare a one single exception, say, `wrong_date_time` and catch it, as follows:

```
create or replace package pkg1 as
  function date_chk(p_value in varchar2, p_format in varchar2) return number;
end;

create or replace package body pkg1 as
  -- This function is simply trying to convert character literal to a value of 
  -- date data type. If it's not possible for whatever reason it raises 
  -- user defined ORA-20001 exception. We will catch it later.
  function to_date1( p_value in varchar2, p_format in varchar2) return date is
  begin
    -- Here we add fx modifier to require exact matching between
    -- character literal and format model, otherwise
    -- something like 21.01 will give us 1, which is not quite correct.
    return to_date(p_value, concat('fx',p_format)); 
  exception
    when others then raise_application_error(-20001, 'wrong date');
  end;

  function date_chk(p_value in varchar2, p_format in varchar2) return number is
    wrong_date_time exception;
    pragma exception_init(wrong_date_time, -20001);
    l_res date;
  begin
    l_res := pkg1.to_date1(p_value, p_format);
    return 1;
  exception
    when wrong_date_time then
      return 0;
  end;
end;
```

Test case:

```
SQL> select pkg1.date_chk('09:99', 'hh24:mi') as res
  2    from dual
  3  ;
       RES
----------
         0

SQL> select pkg1.date_chk('09:59', 'hh24:mi') as res
  2    from dual
  3  ;
       RES
----------
         1

SQL> select pkg1.date_chk('asdas', 'hh24:mi') as res
  2    from dual
  3  ;
       RES
----------
         0
```

Answer (score 2):

You must put in something here:

```
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
  IF SQLCODE = -01858 THEN
   RETURN 0;
  ELSE             -- > Missing in your code
   RETURN SQLCODE; -- > Missing in your code
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks the error is gone but unfortunately I am not getting any of the incorrect time in the return, any idea why?